# Ngfor not changing the old style value

Tags: angular, typescript

In my component html creating the month list using ngfor and calling the function(myColDiv) to set the class(attribute) of the div and setting the variable value for width (some calculation).

> **html**

```
<div  *ngFor="let monthCnt of monthCounts;" >
    <div [attr.class]="myColDiv(monthCnt)">
       <div class="myEventTitleProgress" [style.width]="prjtStartDays+'%'">
         {{prjtStartDays}}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> ts

```
 myColDiv(month) {
      this.prjtStartDays = month*10;
      return "col-"+month;
    }
```

why this.prjtStartDays not binding to old values also , anything wrong on this?

Each div has proper values like 10,20,30,10...120.
How to make all the div width as last value (120).

Comment: Would be easy if you provide a plunkr. Have you tried using [ngStyle] instead of [style]?

Comment: Using [style.width]="prjtStartDays+'%'"

Comment: you want all the columns to be 120% width?

Comment: Yes, width need to be 120 for all div.

Comment: would you please create a stackblitz and share here